# Computer Reasoning about Prologish Boolos' Curious Inference

Tags: prolog, logic, successor-arithmetics

Boolo's curious inference has been originally formulated with equations **[here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30226368)**. It is a recursive definition of a function f and a predicate d via the syntax of N+, the natural numbers without zero, generated from 1 and s(.).

But it can also be formulated with Horn Clauses. The logical content is not exactly the same, the predicate f captures only the positive aspect of the function, but the problem type is the same. Take the following Prolog program:

```
f(_, 1, s(1)).
f(1, s(X), s(s(Y))) :- f(1, X, Y).
f(s(X), s(Y), T) :- f(s(X), Y, Z), f(X, Z, T).

d(1).
d(s(X)) :- d(X).
```

Whats the theoretical logical outcome of the last query, and can you demonstrably have a computer program in our time and space that produces the outcome, i.e. post the program on gist and everybody can run it?

```
?- f(X,X,Y).
X = 1,
Y = s(1) 
X = s(1),
Y = s(s(s(1))) 
X = s(s(1)),
Y = s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(...)))))))))) 
ERROR: Out of global stack

?- f(s(s(s(s(1)))), s(s(s(s(1)))), X), d(X).
```

If the program that does the job of certifying the result is not a Prolog interpreter itself like **[here](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/cbenzmueller/papers/B6.pdf)**, what would do the job especially suited for this Prologish problem formulation?

Comment: `0` and `s(X)` is the common notation in Prolog. See The Art of Prolog

Comment: See [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890933/computer-reasoning-about-prologish-boolos-curious-inference) for references.

Comment: @GuyCoder: I peaked to 15k because of SO's rep-flooding doubling question votes. So this was not me.

Comment: The current one answer is not valid. You need to prove also termination, not only abstract interpretation. The program could be non-well founded but the abstract interpretation might be well founded. We need to exclude this case.

Comment: If it were valid, I would have marked it as the correct answer. Nevertheless I have up voted it for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

## One solution: Abstract interpretation

### Preliminaries

In this answer, I use an **interpreter** to show that this holds. However, it is not a **Prolog** interpreter, because it does not interpret the program in exactly the same way *Prolog* interprets the program.

Instead, it interprets the program in a more *abstract* way. Such interpreters are therefore called **abstract interpreters**.

### Program representation

Critically, I work **directly** with the source program, using only modifications that we, by purely algebraic reasoning, *know* can be safely applied. It helps tremendously for such reasoning that your source program is completely **pure** by construction, since it only uses pure predicates.

To simplify reasoning about the program, I now *make all unifications explicit*. It is easy to see that this does not change the meaning of the program, and can be easily automated. I obtain:

```
f(_, X, Y) :-
        X = 1,
        Y = s(1).
f(Arg, X, Y) :-
        Arg = 1,
        X = s(X0),
        Y = s(s(Y0)),
        f(Arg, X0, Y0).
f(X, Y, T) :-
        X = s(X0),
        Y = s(Y0),
        f(X, Y0, Z),
        f(X0, Z, T).
```

I leave it as an easy exercise to show that this is declaratively equivalent to the original program.

### The abstraction

The abstraction I use is the following: Instead of reasoning over the *concrete* terms `1`, `s(1)`, `s(s(1))` etc., I use the atom **`d`** for each term *T* for which I can **prove** that `d(`*T*`)` holds.

Let me show you what I mean by the following *interpretation* of **unification**:

```
interpret(d = N) :- d(N).
```

This says:

> **If** `d(N)` *holds*, **then** `N` *is to be regarded* identical to the atom `d`, which, as we said, shall denote any term for which `d/1` holds.

Note that this differs *significantly* from what an *actual* unification between concrete terms `d` and `N` means! For example, we obtain:

```
?- interpret(X = s(s(1))).
X = d.
```

Pretty strange, but I hope you can get used to it.

### Extending the abstraction

Of course, interpreting a single unification is not enough to reason about this program, since it also contains additional language elements.

I therefore extend the abstract interpretation to:

- **conjunction**
- calls of **`f/3`**.

Interpreting conjunctions is easy, but what about `f/3`?

### Incremental derivations

If, during abstract interpretation, we encounter the goal `f(X, Y, Z)`, then we know the following: In principle, the arguments can of course be unified with any terms for which the goal **succeeds**. So we keep track of those arguments for which we *know* the query can succeed in principle.

We thus equip the predicate with an additional argument: A list of `f/3` goals that are logical consequences of the program.

In addition, we implement the following very important provision: If we encounter a unification that cannot be safely interpreted in *abstract* terms, then we throw an **error** instead of failing silently. This may for example happen if the unification would *fail* when regarded as an abstract interpretation although it would *succeed* as a concrete unification, or if we cannot fully determine whether the arguments are of the intended domain. The primary purpose of this provision is to avoid unintentional elimination of actual solutions due to oversights in the abstract interpreter. This is the most critical aspect in the interpreter, and any proof-theoretic mechanism will face closely related questions (how can we ensure that no proofs are missed?).

Here it is:

```
interpret(Var = N, _) :-
        must_be(var, Var),
        must_be(ground, N),
        d(N),
        Var = d.
interpret((A,B), Ds) :-
        interpret(A, Ds),
        interpret(B, Ds).
interpret(f(A, B, C), Ds) :-
        member(f(A, B, C), Ds).
```

### Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

How can we tell whether this is actually correct? That's the *tough* part! In fact, it turns out that the above is not sufficient to be certain to catch all cases, because it may simply *fail* if `d(N)` does not hold. It is obviously not acceptable for the abstract interpreter to fail silently for cases it cannot handle. So we need at least one more clause:

```
interpret(Var = N, _) :-
        must_be(var, Var),
        must_be(ground, N),
        \+ d(N),
        domain_error(d, N).
```

In fact, an abstract interpreter becomes a lot less error-prone when we reason about **ground terms**, and so I will use the atom `any` to represent "any term at all" in derived answers.

Over this domain, the interpretation of unification becomes:

```
interpret(Var = N, _) :-
        must_be(ground, N),
        (   var(Var) ->
            (   d(N) -> Var = d
            ;   N = s(d) -> Var = d
            ;   N = s(s(d)) -> Var = d
            ;   domain_error(d, N)
            )
        ;   Var == any -> true
        ;   domain_error(any, Var)
        ).
```

In addition, I have implemented further cases of the unification over this abstract domain. I leave it as an exercise to ponder whether this correctly models the intended semantics, and to implement further cases.

As it will turn out, this definition *suffices* to answer the posted question. However, it clearly leaves a lot to be desired: It is more complex than we would like, and it becomes increasingly harder to tell whether we have covered all cases. Note though that any proof-theoretic approach will face closely corresponding issues: The more complex and powerful it becomes, the harder it is to tell whether it is still correct.

## All derivations: See you at the fixpoint!

It now remains to deduce *everything that follows from the original program*.

Here it is, a simple **fixpoint** computation:

```
derivables(Ds) :-
        functor(Head, f, 3),
        findall(Head-Body, clause(Head, Body), Clauses),
        derivables_fixpoint(Clauses, [], Ds).

derivables_fixpoint(Clauses, Ds0, Ds) :-
        findall(D, clauses_derivable(Clauses, Ds0, D), Ds1, Ds0),
        term_variables(Ds1, Vs),
        maplist(=(any), Vs),
        sort(Ds1, Ds2),
        (   same_length(Ds2, Ds0) -> Ds = Ds0
        ;   derivables_fixpoint(Clauses, Ds2, Ds)
        ).

clauses_derivable(Clauses, Ds0, Head) :-
        member(Head-Body, Clauses),
        interpret(Body, Ds0).
```

Since we are deriving **ground terms**, `sort/2` removes duplicates.

Example query:

```
?- derivables(Ds).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Somewhat anticlimactically, the abstract interpreter is unable to process this program!

## Commutativity to the rescue

In a proof-theoretic approach, we search for, well, *proofs*. In an interpreter-based approach, we can either improve the interpreter *or* apply algebraic laws to transform the source program in a way that preserves essential properties.

In this case, I will do the latter, and leave the former as an exercise. Instead of searching for *proofs*, we are searching for *equivalent ways* to write the program so that our interpreter can derive the desired properties. For example, I now use *commutativity* of conjunction to obtain:

```
f(_, X, Y) :-
        X = 1,
        Y = s(1).
f(Arg, X, Y) :-
        Arg = 1,
        f(Arg, X0, Y0),
        X = s(X0),
        Y = s(s(Y0)).
f(X, Y, T) :-
        f(X, Y0, Z),
        f(X0, Z, T),
        X = s(X0),
        Y = s(Y0).
```

Again, I leave it as an exercise to carefully check that this program is declaratively *equivalent* to your original program.

*iamque opus exegi*, because:

```
?- derivables(Ds).
Ds = [f(any, d, d)].
```

This shows that in *each* solution of `f/3`, the last two arguments are **always** terms for which `d/1` holds! In particular, it *also* holds for the sample arguments you posted, even if there is no hope to ever actually compute the *concrete* terms!

### Conclusion

By abstract interpretation, we have shown:

- for all `X` where `f(_, _, X)` holds, `d(X)` *also* holds
- beyond that, for all `Y` where `f(_, Y, _)` holds, `d(Y)` *also* holds.

The question only asked for a *special case* of the *first* property. We have shown significantly more!

In summary:

> **If** `f(_, Y, X)` holds, **then** `d(X)` holds *and* `d(Y)` holds.

Prolog makes it comparatively easy and convenient to reason about Prolog programs. This often allows us to derive interesting properties of Prolog programs, such as termination properties and type information.

Please see [**Reasoning about programs**](https://www.metalevel.at/acomip/acomip.html#reasoning) for references and more explanation.

+1 for a great question and reference.

Comment: How can such nice analysis be tied much closer to the actual source?

Comment: Do you have a termination proof?